# AWS Support or AWS Expert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am in little confusion, and would like to solve it with your help.

My website is running well on EC2 since last 2-3 months and I got it migrated with one of AWS Expert, now that expert is not in premises and I am little worry how should I proceed to maintain it so that if any minor/major issue occurs with the running EC2 instance can be taken care immediately.

Options in my mind are:

1. Hire a person who is good in AWS, can take care all EC2 maintenance works.
2. Purchase Business support, so that if any major/minor issue occurs can be taken care at earliest, I am in favor of this option since if EC2 goes down nobody can correct it except AWS team which is actively available only when I will be having Business Support.

Please share your feedback.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague but reading between the lines you need support for an application running on EC2, not just the EC2 itself.  I don't think AWS Business Support covers that

Comment: @Vorsprung I have made it little more clear, Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if any minor/major issue occurs with the running EC2 instance can be taken care immediately....  Purchase Business support,

Please see the [Business support plan](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/business-support/).

AWS Business support will help you to stay available, support you to resolve your issues, but they won't do it instead of you. They really won't touch your environment.

This answer is opinion based as you placed no hard requirements for your case.

> Hire a person who is good in AWS, can take care all EC2 maintenance works

If this is viable and feasible depends if you have enough work for such a person or you would pay to stand by. What may be interesting is option of managed hosting. AWS itself doesn't do managed hosting themselves, but there is a list [partners providing managed services](https://aws.amazon.com/managed-services/partners/).

Under managed services there are different service level, but usually the partners will keep pool of AWS certified experts and they can proactively monitor your environment and do something immediately if needed (usually only the infrastructure is supported, not necessary any custom application).